# Call PHP function with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I know I can do this:

```
//Jquery
$.ajax({type: 'POST', data : {'action' : 'foo'}});

//PHP
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'foo')
{
    function foo()
    {
        //yeah
    }
}
```

But.. In a project I'm working on with a friend, he has set up the controllers to be able to have specific functions called using custom actions. For instance, say my view is using the controller of thing.php. From my Javascript I can just AJAX to a url like this:

```
'url' : 'thing'
```

So in this case, foo() would get called without a need for any ifs or switches (as far as I know)

To me, this is great and ideal but I'm not sure how it was set up. He isn't around for the holidays to ask so I'm asking you guys.

Do you know how this is achieved? We are using a pretty typical MVC architecture. Sorry I am a PHP novice. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend what and how he implemented?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: excuse me?

Comment: @zerkms: "*[My friend] isn't around for the holidays to ask so I'm asking you guys.*"

Comment: @DCoder: so? "Someone has implemented something. How does it work?" --- could you answer this?

Comment: @zerkms: not with such a vague description, no. But I would explain *why* I can't answer it, not just tell them to do what they already said they can't do right now.

Comment: I (and afraid that nobody else on SO) have idea how your friend has done this. You can read his/her script. In general, classes are called either dynamically: `$class = new $classType(); $class->$actionName();` or loaded with [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) (the last one is slightly slow but gives more information that maybe used in advanced pre-processing.

Comment: Would like to help but you need to tell us what you are talking about when you "it". Sorry.

Comment: Just to demonstrate: the vague answer for the vague question: http://google.com A bit less vague (still useless though): http://php.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your friend is using .htaccess to rewrite URLS to add `.php`, perhaps with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now if you call a URL like `/thing` it will actually call the file `/thing.php` on your server and execute it. Or in your case if your url is just `thing` without the starting / it will call the `thing.php` in the same folder your current page is in.

Or perhaps he is rewriting everything to the controller and then adding the variable as command. Something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?action=$1
```

Anyway, check your/his .htaccess file for clues

Comment: by the way .htaccess files are often hidden files by default so you won't necessarily see them unless you have hidden files showing.

Comment: btw2> my hosting company uses iirf.ini file instead of .htaccess, so perhaps you could look at that also.